# how to logout from wpf silverlight application

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, logout

In my WPF Application, I have a logout button. What I want is when the user clicks logout he should be taken back to login screen. The below code which I have written was working perfectly few days back. But now its not working as expected. I used to close clear the Layout Root and close the mainwindow and once again I used to open it back. My logout function is as below.

```
 private void Logout_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Global.mainWindow.LayoutRoot.Children.Clear();
            MainWindow mw=Global.mainWindow;
            var mv=new MainWindow();
            mv.Show();
            mw.Close();

        }
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the above code or is there any better way to do it.

If more detail is required then I will edit the same.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to clear the layout if you are closing the same form,

```
Private void Logout_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{            
     var mv=new MainWindow();
     mv.Show();
     this.Close();
}
```

Comment: @Sajeetharan.. Actually that does not  make any difference bro. Even though I remove it the mv.Show() does not work. It just closes the mainwindow.